# Memory with higher Mhz or lower Cast Latency?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm planning to buy memory for my motherboard [Asus AT3IONT-I](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=ZHofno9Kz03TkwXw) which supports:

2 x DIMM, Max. 4 GB DDR3 1066/800 Non-ECC Unbuffered memory and also
Dual Channel memory architecture.

Which of the memories below would be a better choice for this motherboard?

1. 4GB **1066MHz** DDR3 Non-ECC **CL7** DIMM (Kit of 2)
2. 4GB **1333MHz** DDR3 Non-ECC **CL9** DIMM (Kit of 2)

The costs for both sets of memory are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course 1st, 1066MHz.

You will lose advantage of the 1333Mhz variant because your motherboard does not support it, therefore it will still work only at 1066 MHz. Also you will be able to set lower timings on them, but maybe not the CL7.